# TFS project structure makes simple things difficult

Tags: asp.net, tfs, project-management

My team is currently working on an ASP .NET website. We are one of the first teams in our organization to use TFS2008 for source control. When I joined the project, it had already been active for a few months. Below is a diagram of the basic file structure we are using in TFS:

```
$/TfsProject/
|
|   /* Contains our in-house class libraries. */
|-- Common/
|   |
|   |-- Extensions/
|   |   |-- Extensions.csproj
|   |
|   |-- Loggers/
|       |-- Loggers.csproj
|
|   /* Contains third-party libraries. */
|-- Library/
|   |
|   |-- EnterpriseLibrary/
|       |
|       |-- v4.1/
|           |-- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
|
|   /* Contains the website itself. */
|-- Site/
    |
    |-- Packages/
    |   |-- Packages.csproj
    |
    |-- Website.root/
        |
        |-- Website/
            |-- Website.sln
            |
            |-- Website/
            |   |-- Website.csproj
            |   |-- Default.aspx
            |
            |-- WebsiteUnitTests/
            |   |-- WebsiteUnitTests.csproj
            |
            |-- WebsiteWebControls/
            |   |-- WebsiteWebControls.csproj
            |
            |-- Utilities/
                |-- Utilities.csproj
```

The main website solution (`Website.sln`) currently contains fifteen projects (including each of the `.csproj` files displayed in the diagram). Yesterday a decision was made that the projects contained in the `Common` directory should be moved into their own solution, and we should include them in the Website by referencing the compiled DLLs instead of the projects themselves. Anytime one of the `Common` projects is updated, all other projects that use it should begin using the latest version with minimal effort.

Is there any easy way to implement this, based on our current hierarchy? I have read the [TFS patterns & practices](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%203%20-%20Structuring%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20in%20Source%20Control&referringTitle=Home) guide, but implementing any its suggestions would require significant changes (as well as updating all of our projects and solutions). Also, our organization is waiting until TFS2010 is released before they enable Team Builds -- so they're unavailable to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more "portable" solution would be to have a build specifically for the shared projects/solutions.  The last step of those builds is to check in the binaries into a publishing folder (possibly under /libraries).  When getting latest for the client projects (those referencing the binaries) you will end up pulling down the latest binaries.  You don't lose the ability to branch the client projects and team members are free to map folders as they choose.

I will say as a whole, you should reconsider your folder structure.  It doesn't allow for a very flexible branching structure.  You appear to be using your TFS repository much like many VSS users historically have: As a versioned file system.

Comment: Agree with both points.  If nothing else, move Common+Library+Site under one single parent.  Otherwise you'll never be able to branch your code without creating a brand new team project.

Comment: I have brought up branching in the past, but a consensus was reached that it would only complicate things further.

Comment: Branching should really be both a team AND an individual choice, but I understand.  Very small things could be done to make branching incredibly easy for those interested in doing so.  Team members will not impacted by individuals branching for personal productivity.

Answer (score 1):

- A solution that may work is to have
  the projects in Common all output to
  the same directory ("C:\temp\dlls"), 
  rather than each local /bin folder.
- That directory can then be added to
  the Web Project solution. All of the
  references to the DLLS should be made
  to the common folder pulled from TFS.
- That directory can be added to TFS as
  a folder. Everyone on the team will
  have to have the folder mapped
  locally with the same relative path
  to the solution file.
- The place where the "minimal effort"
  piece breaks down is that the files
  will have to be checked in/out when
  compiled. The rest of the team would
  then have to GetLatest. The GetLatest
  requirement may actually be better,
  because you don't want changes forced
  to you while you are in the middle of
  developing.

You basically end up having a folder with compiled dlls added to the web project solution. That is also the same folder that all the Common dlls are built to. That folder is where all the projects in the web solution reference the Common Dlls. When someon rebuilds, they have to check out the dlls in the folder, build and then check back in. When a developer wants the latest, they call GetLatest on the folder and rebuild their projects.

This actually worked for us in a similiar situation where we had compiled dlls to reference. The difference for us is that the compiled dlls chagned so infrequently, that the whole "GetLatest" paradigm never came into play.